# Server 2012 RemoteApp Disconnects/Reconnects Constantly

Tags: windows-server-2012, rdp, remote-desktop-services, remoteapp

I have remote desktop services running on Server 2012 with high availability. I'm running 3 gateways and a farm of session host servers. Gateways all seem to be running fine, they take connections no problem. Each are running around 200 connections simultaneously; we are publishing one application.

Some of our users are reporting a disconnect/reconnect happening intermittently. Since I cant post a screen shot yet, it basically comes up with a window saying "The network connection to the remote computer was lost. Attempting to reconnect.

Sounds pretty self explanatory, right? Well, when checking the connection - I don't see any drops. During these disconnects, I run a ping -t command to our server in hopes to see some bandwidth drops or time outs but I get nothing but a solid stable connection.

I've initiated the keep alive group policy to try an assist but it still happens.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!